# UserType nullSafeGet and nullSafeSet migration

Tags: java, hibernate

Does anyone know how to migrate code from the deprecated Hibernate 3 `nullSafeGet` and `nullSafeSet` methods to the newer Hibernate 4 `nullSafeGet` and `nullSafeSet` methods that take a `SessionImplementor` argument?

I suppose I can simply call the older (deprecated) methods from the newer ones, ignoring the `SessionImplementor` argument. But I am not sure what the implication of that choice would be. In the book "Hibernate Recipes" on page 90, the author(s) ignore the `SessionImplementor` argument.

**Relevant Hibernate documentation of this change**
[Migration guide detailing that the change is happening in v4.0](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCoreMigrationGuide40)
[Hibernate team JIRA report for this change](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5941)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same strategy (ignoring) is  also applied in `org.hibernate.type.EnumType`.

Answer (score 2):

SessionImplementor is there if you need it. Otherwise ignore it